# Python - code not processing all files in directory

Tags: python

The code below is only processing one file in my 'textpath' directory. I am using "for .. in ..:" statement so it should process all the files in the directory. I'm a Python newbie so any help would really be appreciated!

```
textpath = "C:\Users\SL\Documents\FF Project\scratchpad\Text"
newpath = "C:\Users\SL\Documents\FF Project\scratchpad\TextFiles"
text2breaks = os.listdir(textpath)

for text2break in text2breaks:
    file = os.path.join(textpath, text2break)
    textfile=open(file)
    textFileContent=textfile.read()
    textFileList = re.split("[0-9]{1,2} of [0-9]{1,4} DOCUMENTS", textFileContent)
    for item in sorted(set(textFileList)):
        listpos = textFileList.index(item)
        resultsfilename = os.path.join(newpath, text2break[:-4] + "_" + str(listpos) + ".txt" )
        resultsfile = open(resultsfilename, "w")
        resultsfile.writelines(item)
        resultsfile.close()
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  Please **edit** your question and read the formatting guidelines on the right side of the page.

Comment: What is the result of `sorted(set(textFileList))`? Does it have more than one entry?

Comment: Please make sure that you get the formatting of your questions right. Especially with whitespace-sensitive code like `Python` it's hard for us to improve the formatting without destroying your code, functionality and possible error sources. Please check the code I've formatted for indentation errors.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, @buffer: That's what I mean...without the OP rechecking his code, we can't assume anything.

Comment: @Bobby You're right. Correcting spacing instinct from non-python questions :-)

Comment: @cwallenpoole: No problem, I can also hardly control that itch. ;)

Comment: Sorry about that formatting issues (I'm a stackoverflow.com newbie) - won't happen again!

Comment: You should use raw strings for windows paths (`r'string'`). If you don't, a filename starting with a lower case `n`, `t`, etc, can mess you up since your string will contain `\n` and so on.

Comment: Be very, very careful about backslashes. If they're followed by any of `abfnrtv`, they'll be treated as escape codes, plus `\xNN` and for unicode strings (`u''`) `\uNNNN`. In this case you haven't tripped over, but if you put in Windows paths you're best to use raw strings, where backslash doesn't act as an escape code - `r'C:\Users\...'

Answer (score 0):

`textfile=open(file)` statement takes only the last value of the iteration since its outside the loop

You loop should be something like this :

```
for text2break in text2breaks:
    file = os.path.join(textpath, text2break)
    textfile=open(file)
    textFileContent=textfile.read()
    textFileList = re.split("[0-9]{1,2} of [0-9]{1,4} DOCUMENTS", textFileContent)
```

EDIT : The edited question should address that

Comment: And apologies for the formatting issues earlier - its my first time using stackoverflow.com so I posted before I finished formatting the code.